# Android Webview redirect

Tags: android, redirect, webview, back

I meet a problem when I use Webview. 
When I click a link in page A that links to page B, page B redirect to page C. At this time, I want to go back to page A by clicking the back button, but when it backs to page B, it immediately redirects to page C.
I searched the problem in google, but I didn't find the answer, can anyone help? Hear is my code

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    if (url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: put your code what you tried.